# Snowflake error: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Need help with the below query. I'm getting error when executing.

> Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated.

```
    select food.ORGANIZATION_CODE as from_organization_code
    , hlf.ADDRESS_LINE_1 
    , hlt.TOWN_OR_CITY to_town_or_city
    , hlt.POSTAL_CODE to_postal_code
    , hlt.COUNTRY to_country
    , 
    (
    select fl.MEANING
    from EDW_SERVICE_ETL_DB.SS.FND_LOOKUP_VALUES as fl
    where fl.LOOKUP_TYPE = 'SHIP_METHOD'
    and fl.LOOKUP_CODE = mism.SHIP_METHOD
    ) ship_method
    , mism.ATTRIBUTE4
,hlf.LOCATION_CODE
, hlt.LOCATION_CODE
    from EDW_SERVICE_ETL_DB.SS.CSF_MTL_INTERORG_SHIP_METHODS mism
    , EDW_SERVICE_ETL_DB.SS.CSF_HR_LOCATIONS_ALL hlf
    , EDW_SERVICE_ETL_DB.SS.CSF_HR_LOCATIONS_ALL hlt
    , EDW_SERVICE_ETL_DB.SS.ORG_ORGANIZATION_DEFINITIONS food
    , EDW_SERVICE_ETL_DB.SS.CSF_HR_ALL_ORGANIZATION_UNITS fee
    , EDW_SERVICE_ETL_DB.SS.ORG_ORGANIZATION_DEFINITIONS tood
    , EDW_SERVICE_ETL_DB.SS.CSF_HR_ALL_ORGANIZATION_UNITS thou
    
    order by 
    hlf.LOCATION_CODE,
    hlt.LOCATION_CODE
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really want to generate a Cartesian product between all those tables? Are you sure that you’re subquery only returns one value?

Comment: Yes NickW. It will return single value.

Comment: OK - then use Dave's solution below. However, you really ought to learn ANSI SQL join syntax as the join syntax you are using has been outdated for 30+ years. Also, as none of your joins have constraints you're joining every record in every table to every other record in every other table (cartesian product) - which is unlikely to be what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the subquery to the main body of the query

```sql
select food.ORGANIZATION_CODE as from_organization_code
    , hlf.ADDRESS_LINE_1 
    , hlt.TOWN_OR_CITY to_town_or_city
    , hlt.POSTAL_CODE to_postal_code
    , hlt.COUNTRY to_country
    , fl.MEANING ship_method
    , mism.ATTRIBUTE4
    , hlf.LOCATION_CODE
    , hlt.LOCATION_CODE
from EDW_SERVICE_ETL_DB.SS.CSF_MTL_INTERORG_SHIP_METHODS mism
    , EDW_SERVICE_ETL_DB.SS.CSF_HR_LOCATIONS_ALL hlf
    , EDW_SERVICE_ETL_DB.SS.CSF_HR_LOCATIONS_ALL hlt
    , EDW_SERVICE_ETL_DB.SS.ORG_ORGANIZATION_DEFINITIONS food
    , EDW_SERVICE_ETL_DB.SS.CSF_HR_ALL_ORGANIZATION_UNITS fee
    , EDW_SERVICE_ETL_DB.SS.ORG_ORGANIZATION_DEFINITIONS tood
    , EDW_SERVICE_ETL_DB.SS.CSF_HR_ALL_ORGANIZATION_UNITS thou
    , EDW_SERVICE_ETL_DB.SS.FND_LOOKUP_VALUES as fl
where fl.LOOKUP_TYPE = 'SHIP_METHOD'
  and fl.LOOKUP_CODE = mism.SHIP_METHOD
order by 
    hlf.LOCATION_CODE,
    hlt.LOCATION_CODE
```

Comment: Hi Dave, if I do that I'm getting more records than what I expect. It's probably pulling duplicates not sure why.

Comment: As @NickW mentioned, you have no join criteria or where clause to filter the rows. This ends up joining all rows in all tables to each other. This is called a cartesian join. Without knowing more about the tables, I cannot make further suggestions other that to say you will need to add join information to properly constrain the output. One additional observation: it does not appear that you need fee, tood, or thou tables as no columns are used in the query.

Comment: Finally, the hlf and hlt tables are the same table. Again, you need some kind of join criteria to stop joining all rows in all the tables.